# Securing AWS RDS credentials for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

Right now I am passing the username and password in as environment variables. The variables are retrieved from a different file so the cloudformation stored using git does not contain the password and username which is good. But, right now they are stored in plaintext when looking at the lambda in the console.

What is the best practice for storing these credentials in the most cloud provider agnostic way? I basically just don't want to use KMS or any other key storing AWS service.

Just for completeness I have also considered storing the password in a dynamodb table. Then I would use IAM to be able to retrieve those credentials. But, those credentials are still stored in plaintext. If this is the best way to retrieve credentials is there a best way to encrypt it or this path not the best.

Thanks for all comments and advice.

Comment: Using the AWS services like SSM parameter store or Secrets Manager are the standard approach. Why are you opposed to them?

Comment: The reason I am hesitant to use AWS services is because of the throttling that occurs at relatively low rates of requests. That is why I was interested in DynamoDB because we know it can handle the requests regardless of the lambda rates. Also, I may be incorrect,but, the way I think parameter store and Secrets Manager would work but be to make a credentials request each time a lambda executes. Ideally, I would want to store the credentials some way to avoid making that call every time.

Comment: You don’t avoid a service because of rate limit, you learn to work within the limits and implement retry logic with exponential backoff, caching etc. Besides are you really expecting to fetch the secret more than 700 times per second?

Comment: I do not expect to. However, I am a student and I really just wanted to explore designing a scalable architecture for a web app. If I worked for a company building this, a simple CRUD operation to an RDS database, it surely would exceed 700 times per second. (I know at a certain point Lambda becomes more costly than EC2 but I still wanted to use Lambda) Also, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) for this exact situation.  Works perfectly for us.

Comment: The reason I am hesitant to use AWS services is because of the throttling that occurs at relatively low rates of requests. That is why I was interested in DynamoDB because we know it can handle the requests regardless of the lambda rates. Also, I may be incorrect,but, the way I think parameter store and Secrets Manager would work but be to make a credentials request each time a lambda executes. Ideally, I would want to store the credentials some way to avoid making that call every time. Are you making a request or just filling the some variable once when you update the cloudformation template?

Comment: If you're being throttled at low request rates then you can contact AWS support to request a limit increase.  Even if you are throttled, there are a number of battle tested strategies you can implement to handle this. We use Secrets Manager in a high frequency trading platform and we don't face any issues with it; I don't know your application, but it should meet most needs pretty comfortably.

Comment: Ok thanks! Just out of curiosity for this trading platform do you use serverless tools for most of your operations or is most of the heavy lifting done in EC2 with few lambda executions?

Comment: Entirely built on Serverless Framework; not a single EC2 instance (or other type of instance) in our environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any advice or resources for learning how to architect large scale systems like that? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Also, do you rotate the credentials using Secrets Manager?

Comment: Best practice would be to rotate secrets regularly.